# Expected spectral radius for a sparse Erdős-Rényi binary matrix with a certain density

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, random-matrices, sparse-matrices, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ sparse matrix generated via the [Erdős-Rényi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) method. Here, "sparse" means that $\|A\|_F = O(n)$. I am interested in the relationship between the expectation $\mathbb E(\rho(A))$ and the Erdős-Rényi density $p$ when $n$ is large.

Using MATLAB, I find that when $A$ is sparse (i.e., the density is small), the expectation of the spectral radius is almost linear in the matrix density. Can this result somehow be proved?

Any reference or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean the adjacency matrix of a random E-R graph?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that $A$ is the adjacency matrix of an Erdos-Renyi random graph, then the question has been studied, and your conjecture is false (but just barely). See

*Krivelevich, Michael; Sudakov, Benny*, [**The largest eigenvalue of sparse random graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0963548302005424), Comb. Probab. Comput. 12, No.1, 61-72 (2003). [ZBL1012.05109](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1012.05109).

(available on arxiv.org).